# Proving points lie on a straight line (geometric proof)

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

I am struggling to understand what criteria to look for when trying to prove that $A$, $B$ and $N$ are on a straight line in the question below:

[image]

I can work out the interior angle at $ B$ as $150$ and the exterior angle as $30$. The angle $BCN$ is $120$, but I cannot see why this is sufficient to draw the conclusion that $N$ will be on the projection of $AB$?

Comment: Looks like you are done.  $\Delta BCN$ is isosceles so $\angle CBN=\angle CNB=30$.

Comment: @Lulu How do I know that $CBN = 30$? I know the exterior angle is $30$, but my brain is struggling to be convinced that this $CBN$ is the exterior angle?

Comment: @Lulu I was being silly, thank you - it's the isosceles triangle part!

Comment: No worries.  Like I said, you were nearly done.

Answer (score 2):

You would like to prove that $A\hat{B}N = 180^\circ$ and since $A\hat{B}C = 150^\circ$, it suffices to show that $N\hat{B}C = 30^\circ$.

Note that triangle $BCN$ is an isosceles triangle. Can you take it from here?